# Mysql Ordering by date

Tags: mysql

I have a date field in my table called date1. if i use the following query.

```
 select * from schedule order by date1 asc

 it gives the result like as jan 2011 comes before december 2010. but i need the december 2011 as the first row of the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to

`SELECT * FROM schedule ORDER BY date1 DESC`

This should do the trick.

James

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from schedule order by date1 desc
```